# What comes after quadruple

Tags: word-request

I tried searching in my dictionary and google, but didnt find anything.

1. Single
2. Double
3. Triple
4. Quadruple
5. ?
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?

Comment: Do you have Google in your country?

Comment: Yes, but it showed nothing.

Comment: I typed 'after quadruple' into Google and got 'about 25,500,000 results'. You don't even need to click the links, you can read the answer from the search results.

Answer (score 2):

Quintuple, sextuple, septuple, octuple, nonuple, decuple.